# Passing variable from URL + Selecting from SQL and Echoing it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Title is a little hard to understand, so basically I'm making a Pastebin clone and am attempting to do a kind of viewmember.php?id=1213 thing for viewing pastes. However, I can't figure it out at all. I've done a lot of research, and after finally understanding what I had to do (or so I thought) I made this up and don't know why it isn't working.

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
    $getid = $_GET["id"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pasteinfo WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $getid);
    echo $stmt;
```

?>

I'm probably just stupid. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to execute the statement to actually get any results.

Comment: How do I do that? dont crucify me please

Comment: ...and you won't be able to echo the results like that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the command to execute the query.

```
$sql = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM pasteinfo WHERE id = ?"; // Specify fields in query
$stmt->bind_param("i", $getid);  /* bind parameters for markers */
$stmt->execute();  /* execute query */
$stmt->bind_result($field1, $field2); /* bind result variables */
$stmt->fetch();    /* fetch value */
echo "Field 1:".$field1;
echo "Field 2:".$field2;
```

Reference: [Example #1 mysqli::prepare() example](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-examples)

Comment: Thanks! How do I echo the result?

Comment: In order to echo the result, it's the best if you specify the fields in `SELECT` instead of mentioning `SELECT *`

Comment: $result = $stmt->execute();   foreach($result  as $val){    echo $val->item_name;  }

Comment: Don't really see what you mean Object Manipulator with the fields. I'm not trying to make a search box or anything, just allow them to access pastes through the URL like the example in the OP. Maybe I'm stupid, not sure, but where do the fields fit in?

Answer (score 0):

```
// save result in a variable and then run a loop and echo 
$result = $stmt->execute(); 

foreach($result as $val){ 
    echo $val->item_name; 
}
```

Comment: Trying to use that in my code but it isn't working. This is how it looks with it: <?php
 require 'connection.php';
  $getid = $_GET["id"];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM pasteinfo WHERE id = ?";
  $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param("i", $getid);



$result = $stmt->execute(); // save result in a variable and then run a loop and echo 

foreach($result as $val){ 
    echo $val->item_name; 
}


?>

Comment: remove  this       // save result in a variable and then run a loop and echo

Comment: @Rafij nothing's happened

Comment: run this  line                                                                                                 echo " <pre>" ; print_r($result);

Comment: @Rafij the web page displays '1'